# Unity3d 2021.2.x Default Unity icon for android

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-editor

I have installed all the unity3d 2021.2.xx versions, and all of them shows unity default icon as app icon for android builds on test phones. It works fine for iOS.

[image]

- Used existing working projects with the new versions.
- Tried opening brand new projects with the new versions.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m experiencing the same thing – things were fine for a long time, but now that I’m on Unity 2021.2.5 the Android icon has switched from my custom one to the default Unity one when I build to APK and install. No settings were changed to prompt this. Clean builds, reimporting the icon texture, etc make no difference. I’m a bit flummoxed and hope someone has a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known regression issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-the-default-icon-does-not-get-successfully-changed-to-another-icon) in Unity 2021.2.x, where using the default icon settings doesn’t work. I can reproduce it in Unity 2021.2.7.

In the mean time, you can specify the adaptive icon, which will work on Android 8+. Here is a [guide to creating the layers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) you need for this to look nice. As adaptive icons only work for Android 8 onwards, devices running earlier versions might still show the default Unity icon while this bug is open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and upgraded Unity to version 2021.2.19f1 and the problem was fixed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31489436)